# Difference between "time" and "mediantime" in getblock?

Tags: bitcoind

For bitcoin-cli getblock, what's the difference between "time" and "mediantime"?

If i'm looking for a strictly increasing series of timestamps, is one better to choose than the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mediantime is better for your purpose. The timestamp is chosen by the miners, and has some restrictions on it such as it can't be too far in the future/past (no more than 2 hours into the future), but it is not strictly increasing. Mediantime, on the other hand, is. Mediantime is the median time of the past 11 block timestamps, and a block *must* have a timestamp greater than that median time, so the mediantime always increases.

Comment: So it's possible to have a higher block with a lower time than a lower block?!

Comment: Correct, as long as it obeys the other rules

Comment: To add to this answer, it would be good to reference BIP113 which explains a bit more on how GetMedianTimePast is used: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0113.mediawiki